# dyld Library not loaded. Reason: tried (no such file)

Tags: ios, xcode, linker, frameworks

1. Created Framework project (SetOfDependencies)
2. Added subframework (Intercom.framework) to this framework project  (SetOfDependencies)
3. Made a build for device
4. Created Client app (ClientGame)
5. Added this Framework (SetOfDependencies.framework) to the client app
6. Embedded and signed
7. Build succeeded but got this error:

```
dyld[2748]: Library not loaded: '@rpath/Intercom.framework/Intercom'

  Referenced from: '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4A1810D3-FCFB-4136-83AA-D2A6EE14F3D9/ClientGame.app/Frameworks/SetOfDepenedencies.framework/SetOfDepenedencies'

  Reason: tried: '/usr/lib/swift/Intercom.framework/Intercom' (no such file), '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4A1810D3-FCFB-4136-83AA-D2A6EE14F3D9/ClientGame.app/Frameworks/Intercom.framework/Intercom' (no such file), '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4A1810D3-FCFB-4136-83AA-D2A6EE14F3D9/ClientGame.app/Frameworks/SetOfDepenedencies.framework/Frameworks/Intercom.framework/Intercom' (code signature in <97C5FB2D-3C3D-3FE5-B90A-2180A2C2CCBC> '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4A1810D3-FCFB-4136-83AA-D2A6EE14F3D9/ClientGame.app/Frameworks/SetOfDepenedencies.framework/Frameworks/Intercom.framework/Intercom' not valid for use in process: mapped file has no cdhash, completely unsigned? Code has to be at least ad-hoc signed.), '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4A1810D3-FCFB-4136-83AA-D2A6EE14F3D9/ClientGame.app/Frameworks/Intercom.framework/Intercom' (no such file), '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4A1810D3-FCFB-4136-83AA-D2A6EE14F3D9/ClientGame.app/Frameworks/Intercom.framework/Intercom' (no such file), '/System/Library/Frameworks/Intercom.framework/Intercom' (no such file)

Library not loaded: '@rpath/Intercom.framework/Intercom'

  Referenced from: '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4A1810D3-FCFB-4136-83AA-D2A6EE14F3D9/ClientGame.app/Frameworks/SetOfDepenedencies.framework/SetOfDepenedencies'

  Reason: tried: '/usr/lib/swift/Intercom.framework/Intercom' (no such file), '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4A1810D3-FCFB-4136-83AA-D2A6EE14F3D9/ClientGame.app/Frameworks/Intercom.framework/Intercom' (no such file), '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4A1810D3-FCFB-4136-83AA-D2A6EE14F3D9/ClientGame.app/Frameworks/SetOfDepenedencies.framework/Frameworks/Intercom.framework/Intercom' (code signature in <97C5FB2D-3C3D-3FE5-B90A-2180A2C2CCBC> '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4A1810D3-FCFB-4136-83AA-D2A6EE14F3D9/ClientGame.app/Frameworks/SetOfDepenedencies.framework/Frameworks/Intercom.framework/Intercom' not valid for use in process: mapped file has no cdhash, completely unsigned? Code has to be at least ad-hoc signed.), '/private/var/containers/Bundle/
```

The compiled result of the Client app:
[image: The compiled result of the Client app]

The compiled result of the Client app:
[image: Framework Search Paths in Build Settings of Client app]

**What do I have to understand from this error and how to fix it?**

Comment: "no such file" says you are looking in the wrong place for the files. Why are you putting it in `/usr/lib/swift/Intercom.framework/`? Why is this "@rpath" and not $rpath or more correctly the actual path directory?